# How do I make my program stop having build issues and make it stop using negative numbers?

Tags: c++, math, build-error

My program needs to be able to calculate the monthly phone bill and there are 3 plans: Basic where 10 hours are free and it costs 9.95, Gold where 20 hours are free and it costs 14.95, and Platinum where you have unlimited hours and it costs 19.95. When my program is given hours less than the free hours it subtracts them from the initial cost, and also it has build hours.

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Set up the variables.
    string input;
    int hours;
    int basicHours;
    int goldHours;
    float extraBasic;
    float basicCost;
    float goldCost;

    // Will ask and display the user their plan and hours.
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to the Comms4You Telecom Company!" << endl;
    cout << "Please provide your plan." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << input << ", Ok now please provide the amount of hours you used." << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    //Calculate different equations
     basicHours = (hours - 10);
     goldHours = (20 - hours);
     extraBasic = (basicHours * 2);
     basicCost = (9.95 + extraBasic);
     goldCost = (14.95 + goldHours);
    //This part is for displaying to the users plans and hours.(Also calculations)
     if (input == "Platinum") {
         cout << "Our company thanks you for using " << hours << " hours! " << "Your total cost is $19.95.";
     }
     else if (input == "Gold") {
         cout << "Our company thanks you for using " << hours << " hours! " << "Your total cost is $" << goldCost << ".";
     }
     else if (input == "Basic") {
         cout << "Our company thanks you for using " << hours << " hours! " << "Your total cost is $" << basicCost << ".";
     }
     else
        return 0; 

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: If you are having build issues why did you not find it relevant to include the error/warning messages for us to see?

Comment: If you don't want to count negative values, maybe just check if the value is negative? If it is, assign it to whatever your default is.

Comment: Separate the input -- you can just hardcode it for your [mcve] instead of reading input. Write a function that computes whatever it is you want to compute. Provide test cases where the input and output of that function don't meet some "correct" or expected value.

Comment: What is the cost per hour for the calls that exceed the free hours of each plan? Could you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: The Build Errors don't show when I debug it in Visual Studio.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the parentheses in `basicHours = (hours - 10);`. They're distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
     basicHours = (hours - 10);
     goldHours = (20 - hours);
     extraBasic = (basicHours * 2);
     basicCost = (9.95 + extraBasic);
     goldCost = (14.95 + goldHours);
```

Think about what they are doing.

### `basicHours = (hours - 10);`

If hours was 11, then basicHours is now `11 - 10 = 1`. This is good. But if hours was 9, then basicHours is now `9 - 10 = -1`. This is not what you want; if I used less than my 10 free hours, then you want basicHours to be 0.
So you can write instead:

```
if (hours > 10) {
    basicHours = hours - 10;
}
else {
    basicHours = 0;
}
```

or equivalently:

```
basicHours = (hours > 10) ? hours - 10 : 0;
```

### `goldHours = (20 - hours)`

This should be the exact same thing as basicHours, except with 20 instead of 10! I will let you adapt the above code.

### `basicCost = (9.95 + extraBasic);` and `goldCost = (14.95 + goldHours);`

This is wrong. `9.95` is a monetary value, say in euros. `extraBasic` is a time, in hours. You cannot add hours with euros! If I used 12 hours with the basic plan, what is the result of `9.95€ + 2h`? I do not know, it does not make sense.

If I used 12 hours with the basic plan, then I have to pay 9.95€, and I have to pay for the extra 2h. What is the cost of the extra 2h? It is 2 times the cost of an hour; in other words, it's the extra time multiplied by the hourly rate. You should have a constant variable called `hourlyRate` or `basicHourlyRate` in your program, with that value. Then you can write:

```
basicCost = 9.95 + extraBasic * basicHourlyRate;
goldCost = 14.95 + goldHours * goldHourlyRate;
```

### Coding style: separate data and code

A good rule to follow is never to put data in your code. All literal values are data. The cost of the basic and gold and platinum plans are data. The hourly rate is data. The number of "free" hours for each plan is data. Define a few variables with explicit names, initialize those variables with the data at the very beginning of the code, then write the rest of the code without ever using a literal value. There are two reasons why this is important.

1. **The code will be easier to read with variables.** Explicit names in variables make the code meaningful; if you use literal values inside the code, the people reading your code don't know what those values stand for. Why do you subtract `10` from `hours`? We have to think about where this `10` comes from. However, if you write `basicPayingHours = hours - freeBasicHours`, we understand immediately. "The people reading your code" include StackOverflow members you're showing your code to, but also your schoolmates or coworkers, your teacher or boss, and most importantly, yourself when you read your code again six months from now.
2. **When the data changes, it will be a lot easier to update your code if data is cleanly separated from code.** Imagine you are working for this phone company. Next year, they update their plans and the basic plan is now 9.99 per month instead of 9.95. If this value is stored at the beginning of your code in a line `basicPlanInitialCost = 9.95;`, it is very easy to update it. However if there are multiple occurrences of 9.95 in your code, you will have to track them and change them all manually - this process is very prone to errors for two reasons: you might accidentally change the cost of something else that also costs 9.95; you might forget to update values that are dependent on the monthly price of the basic cost (like the yearly price of the basic cost, which is `12 * 9.95 = 119.40`).

Comment: I am sorry that this question is worded badly and confusing, this is my first time using this site to ask for help